# What prevents fancybox to load properly after pages are repainted?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Please somebody take a look at my jquery scripts, why are they fighting? After I've enabled page transitions with help of swup, fancybox galleries stopped to work properly, clicking on an image makes it go full screen instead of opening the fancybox image overlay. But sometimes after pressing back, the fancybox loads. Other times, back button has no effect and I have to refresh the page. Example problem pages: https://www.corebots.design/photologue/gallerylist/gallery/rohace-mountains/

tried to wrap the fancybox function with "swup:contentReplaced" like other scripts but it doesn't work.

```
function init() {
    if (document.querySelector('#fancybox')) {
        (function( $ ) {
          $(function() {
                $("#fancybox").fancybox();
          });
        })(jQuery);
    }
}

// initialize swup for pages transitions
const swup = new Swup();


swup.on('contentReplaced', init);

// trying to reload fancybox as suggested by swup doc https://swup.js.org/getting-started/reloading-javascript
document.addEventListener('swup:contentReplaced', function () {

(function( $ ) {
          $(function() {
                $("#fancybox").fancybox();
          });
        })(jQuery);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that could interfere is `history` feature, you can disable that by setting:

```
$("#fancybox").fancybox({
  history: false
});
```

Comment: Hi @Janis and thanks for your suggestion. 

Do you mean like this? 

'
    function init() {
        if (document.querySelector('#fancybox')) {
            (function( $ ) {
              $(function() {
                    $("#fancybox").fancybox({
                        history: false
                    });
              });
            })(jQuery);
        }
    }
'
I've added it this way to both but it has no effect. I still see the fancybox navigation arrows while the image starts loading, but once loaded, it jumps directly to a fullscreen image :( It's so frustrating

Comment: Does fancybox 'history: false' setting have something related to the way how swup repaints the pages? Or what do you think is the problem and how is history: false suppose to solve it ? Thanks @Janis

Comment: A live demo/page would help a lot (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)